# File upload issue for MEAN stack project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am implementing file upload in my project using MEAN stack technologies. I can upload any file size in localhost and on server I can't upload large size file. I am using IIS to host my application and below is the error i am getting.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this. Thanks in advance.

> error :{"description":"Invalid
>   character","number":-2146827274,"stack":"SyntaxError: Invalid
>   character\n   at Anonymous function
>   (http://dnsname/app.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:138:24522)\n   at
>   processQueue (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:5:11546)\n
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:5:12407)\n   at
>   Scope.prototype.$digest
>   (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:5:23153)\n   at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:5:25646)\n   at
>   completeOutstandingRequest
>   (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:2:12288)\n   at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://dnsname/vendor.e1bbd3f7f504d4815f2b.js:2:15454)"}

Comment: pls add some of your code to understand how you are doing it

Comment: I need to use Blob.slice method. Can anyone tell me how to use it.